# Multi-Page Form in Zend is Validating All Forms too early

Tags: zend-framework

I have been working through the Multi Page forms tutorial in the Zend Form Advanced Usage section of the documentation, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html.

My first page loads fine, however when I submit it, the second page loads and it includes validation error messages.  (Obviously I don't want to see validation errors for this page until the user has filled in the fields...)

I have tracked it down to the final line in the formIsValid() function.  It seems that here validation is run for all elements in the three forms (not just the current one), so it's really no surprise that errors are showing on the second page.

I have tried the suggestion in the comments at the end of the tutorial, i.e. $data[$key] = $info[$key].

Have you had a crack at this tutorial?  How did you solve the problem?

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Kim, can you post your code so I can have a look at it? Also, what is the Framework version you're using?

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for the response.  (I see you have this working nicely on your site!)  I have narrowed my problem down to validators, and have started a separate question on it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699395/zend-elements-and-setrequired-setallowempty-notempty

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem this is how I solve it.

By replacing

```
public function formIsValid()
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($this->getSessionNamespace() as $key => $info) {
            $data[$key] = $info;
        }

        return $this->getForm()->isValid($data);
    }
```

With

```
   public function formIsValid()
    { 
       $data = array();
        foreach ($this->getSessionNamespace() as $key => $info) {
            $data[$key] = $info[$key];
        }
        return (count($this->getStoredForms()) < count($this->getPotentialForms()))? false : $this->getForm()->isValid($data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentations reads:

> Currently, Multi-Page forms are not
>   officially supported in Zend_Form;
>   however, most support for implementing
>   them is available and can be utilized
>   with a little extra tooling.
>
> The key to creating a multi-page form
>   is to utilize sub forms, but to
>   display only one such sub form per
>   page. This allows you to submit **a
>   single sub form at a time** and
>   validate it, but not process the form
>   until all sub forms are complete.

Are you sure you have been validating a single sub-form instead of just whole form?

Comment: Thanks Akond.  Yes, the idea is that you validate the individual subform, and store it in the session when it's valid.  Then you attempt to validate the entire form, as a test for whether all forms have been submitted or not...

Comment: If you really want to do that you have to keep all the input for all the subforms. But I wouldn't do it that way.